# How can I use rebus with simpleinjector

Tags: c#, simple-injector, rebus

In my company we are using SimpleInjector as our IoC framework and are now looking at using Rebus as a wrapper for sending messages via RabbitMq. I am looking for help in creating a working example. I have tried the following code:

```
using Rebus.Activation;
using Rebus.Config;
using Rebus.Handlers;
using Rebus.Pipeline;
using Rebus.RabbitMq;
using Rebus.SimpleInjector;
using SimpleInjector;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SearchType.ProjectionA
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Register<IContainerAdapter, SimpleInjectorContainerAdapter>();
        container.Register<IHandleMessages<string>, Handler>();

        var adapter = container.GetInstance<IContainerAdapter>();

        var bus = Configure.With(adapter)
            .Logging(l => l.ColoredConsole())
            .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMq("amqp://localhost", "simpleinjector_consumer"))
            .Start();

        bus.Subscribe<string>().Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Projection A listening - press ENTER to quit");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

public class Handler : IHandleMessages<string>
{
    public Task Handle(string message)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
       {
           Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", MessageContext.Current.Message.Headers["rbs2-corr-id"], message));
       });
    }
}
}
```

When i try and run this console application I am getting the following error:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The container can't be changed after the first call to GetInstance, GetAllInstances and Verify. The following stack trace describes the location where the container was locked:

   at SearchType.ProjectionA.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\HRG\TravTech\Springboard\SearchType\SearchType.ProjectionA\Program.cs:line 34
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

  Source=SimpleInjector
  StackTrace:
       at SimpleInjector.Container.ThrowWhenContainerIsLocked()
       at SimpleInjector.Container.AddRegistration(Type serviceType, Registration registration)
       at SimpleInjector.Container.RegisterSingleton[TService](TService instance)
       at Rebus.SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorContainerAdapter.SetBus(IBus bus)
       at Rebus.Config.RebusConfigurer.Start()
       at SearchType.ProjectionA.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\HRG\TravTech\Springboard\SearchType\SearchType.ProjectionA\Program.cs:line 36
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? I don't want to have to declare all the dependencies myself.

---

**Edit**: thank you Steven for your reply. I have changed the code according to your answer and am now getting a different error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type IMessageContext failed. The registered delegate for type IMessageContext threw an exception. Attempted to inject the current message context from MessageContext.Current, but it was null! Did you attempt to resolve IMessageContext from outside of a Rebus message handler?
  Source=SimpleInjector
  StackTrace:
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyInstanceCreation()
       at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInstanceCreation(InstanceProducer[] producersToVerify)
       at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllRootObjectsCanBeCreated()
       at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInternal(Boolean suppressLifestyleMismatchVerification)
       at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify()
       at SearchType.ProjectionA.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\HRG\TravTech\Springboard\SearchType\SearchType.ProjectionA\Program.cs:line 27
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=The registered delegate for type IMessageContext threw an exception. Attempted to inject the current message context from MessageContext.Current, but it was null! Did you attempt to resolve IMessageContext from outside of a Rebus message handler?
       Source=SimpleInjector
       StackTrace:
            at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
            at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyInstanceCreation()
       InnerException: 
            HResult=-2146233079
            Message=Attempted to inject the current message context from MessageContext.Current, but it was null! Did you attempt to resolve IMessageContext from outside of a Rebus message handler?
            Source=Rebus.SimpleInjector
            StackTrace:
                 at Rebus.SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorContainerAdapter.<SetBus>b__7()
                 at lambda_method(Closure )
                 at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildAndReplaceInstanceCreatorAndCreateFirstInstance()
                 at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
            InnerException:
```

The error indicates that IMessageContext can only be instantiated inside a message handler. Is there a way to ignore certain errors?

Answer (score 1):

I think the exception is clear; Simple Injector prevents registration after you already resolved. Reasons for doing this are described [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decisions.html#container-is-locked).

The solution is to manually create the `SimpleInjectorContainerAdapter` and prevent relying on the container's auto-wiring capability for the adapter:

```cs
var container = new Container();

IContainerAdapter adapter = new SimpleInjectorContainerAdapter(container);

container.Register<IHandleMessages<string>, Handler>();

var bus = Configure.With(adapter)
    .Logging(l => l.ColoredConsole())
    .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMq("amqp://localhost", "simpleinjector_consumer"))
    .Start();

container.Verify();
```